# Find out ids for telegram instances

Tags: telegram, mtproto

Where can I found ids (class ids) for telegram objects that aren't listed in [API TL-Schema](https://core.telegram.org/schema)? (I mean id is like #bc799737 for [boolFalse](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/boolFalse)#bc799737)

For example, on [Perfect Forward Secrecy](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end/pfs) page there are such instances as:

- decryptedMessageActionRequestKey
- decryptedMessageActionAcceptKey
- decryptedMessageActionCommitKey
- decryptedMessageActionAbortKey

But links for them are broken: [decryptedMessageActionRequestKey](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/decryptedMessageActionRequestKey).

How can I figure them out?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the full schema here: (version 70 presently)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/dev/Telegram/Resources/scheme.tl

Note, depending on the schema version, some functions, or object might have been dropped.